# Android xml bundle format doesn't recognize aapt properties

Tags: android, android-animation, aapt, android-vectordrawable

I have tried using Android xml bundle format with example provided in [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html#OneXML), but Android Studio keeps saying that

> 'drawable' or 'animation' attribute should be defined ([See the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZZy6.png))

What can be done in this case to fix the error?

```
<!-- drawable\some_anim.xml-->
<animated-vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
<aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
    <vector
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp"
        android:viewportHeight="600"
        android:viewportWidth="600">
        <group
            android:name="rotationGroup"
            android:pivotX="300.0"
            android:pivotY="300.0"
            android:rotation="45.0">
            <path
                android:name="v"
                android:fillColor="#000000"
                android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z"/>
        </group>
    </vector>
</aapt:attr>

<target android:name="rotationGroup">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="6000"
            android:propertyName="rotation"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="360"/>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>

<target android:name="v">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="3000"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z"
                android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
                android:valueType="pathType"/>
        </set>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
```

Comment: Please post a complete example which illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add extra things in some of tags

at

```
<android vector add    android:drawable="">
```

and In target tags

```
    <target add android:animation="">
```

and lastly added prefix to some tags at

```
    <aapt android:name="android:animation">
```

this is whole code copy and paste it and then check:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:drawable="@color/divider">
<aapt:attr android:name="android:drawable">
    <vector
        android:height="64dp"
        android:width="64dp"
        android:viewportHeight="600"
        android:viewportWidth="600" >
        <group
            android:name="rotationGroup"
            android:pivotX="300.0"
            android:pivotY="300.0"
            android:rotation="45.0" >
            <path
                android:name="v"
                android:fillColor="#000000"
                android:pathData="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z" />
        </group>
    </vector>
</aapt:attr>

<target android:name="rotationGroup"
    android:animation="@android:anim/slide_out_right"> 
    <aapt:attr android:name="android:animation">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="6000"
            android:propertyName="rotation"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="360" />
    </aapt:attr>
</target>

<target android:name="v"
    android:animation="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator">
    <aapt:attr android:name="android:animation">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="3000"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:valueFrom="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,70 0,0 -70,70z"
                android:valueTo="M300,70 l 0,-70 70,0  0,140 -70,0 z"
                android:valueType="pathType"/>
        </set>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
```

Comment: Actually, the point of Android xml bundle format is to declare drawables and animators within the animated-vector itself, instead of reffering to separate files.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove android "cordova platform rm android" and re-added with this command "cordova